# Деплой приложения на Django REST API, Celery, Redis and Postgres с помощью Docker

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, redis, celery

Всем привет. Нужно задеплоить приложение. Все работает без Docker.
Но нужно поместить в докер и запустить на другой машине.

docker-compose

```
    service:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER='user'
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD='password'
      - POSTGRES_DB='db'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web_service:
    container_name: web_service
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER='user'
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD='password'
      - POSTGRES_DB= 'db'
    build: .
    command: sh -c "wait-for db:5432 && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db


  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: "redis:alpine"

  celery_worker:
    container_name: celery_worker
    build: .
    command: sh -c "wait-for redis:6379 && wait-for web_service:8000 -- celery -A mysite worker -l info"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
COPY centrality-service centrality-service
RUN cd centrality-service
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR centrality-service
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python3 myapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Пишет ошибку `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for service: 'celery'`
Читаю документацию и думаю нужно уделить время на это.
Может кто увидит в чем трабл, буду благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окей. Решил проблему и все запустилось

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.9
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    container_name: "web_service"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    build: .
    command: python3 myapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis


  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

  celery:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "cd myapi && celery -A myapi worker -l info"
    depends_on:
      - web
      - db
      - redis
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
COPY centrality-service centrality-service
WORKDIR centrality-service
RUN bash gtg_install.sh
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python3 myapi/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```